Can't I access my Node.js server in my container with localhost?
I am actually learning how to develop a website with Angular and to learn even more we are also learning Docker my putting our project in a container.
Our goal is to have Angular exclusively installed on the container, and have our code on our host machine accessible for the container by a bind volume mounted.
So I created a Dockerfile with what was needed and a docker-compose.yaml so the mount volume instruction is directly in it (so we don't need to run the container with -v each time).
The server launch perfectly, all my files are changed on my container when I modify themn on my host. However, if I want to access it from my host, I have to access it with the "Network" IP provided my Node.js and not the localhost one, and I thought it was supposed to ?
Watch mode enabled. Watching for file changes...
  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:4200/
  ➜  Network: http://another.ip:4200/

I can work with that but I would like to understand why does it work like that, because I think it's just some incomprehension of mine.
Here is my Dockerfile :
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@16

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check"]

And my docker-compose.yaml :
version: '3.8'
services:
  my-website:
    image: image-of-mywebsite
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"

They are in the same folder, the folder where my Angular project is, and I run it with
sudo docker compose run my-website
Thank you for helping me understand.

are you trying to open http://another.ip:4200/ in the browser ?

A Docker container is an isolated environment, with an isolated filesystem, network environment, and other features.  Instead of hiding the Node interpreter in a container and then trying to disable the containerization features, would it be easier to directly run Node on the host?  You would not need to work around troubles with Docker bind mounts and you would have the simpler network setup you're hoping for.

@Andrei actually no, it work if I do it but I remember that prior to that, I could access it by going on my host at http://localhost:4200

The issue could be in the docker-compose.yaml. It runs the image, not the build. Try removing this line:
image: image-of-mywebsite

And then run the composition like this:
docker-compose build && docker-compose up


thank you it actually worked ! I just removed the image from the docker-compose.yaml, but I have a few questions. Why doesn't it work with run but it's okay when i build && up ? And I thought if I use image and then build, image was just a name i would attribute to the image used once built.

To use the image property, to you have to either build and publish the image properly or build and tag it locally.The run command does something entirely different. It runs a command in a service. It like up, but it does run an additional command.

ok I understand better now thanks a lot

Have you tried http://0.0.0.0:4200/ or http://127.0.0.1:4200/?
You can try as well removing the --host flag in your CMD command such as:
CMD ["ng", "serve" "--disable-host-check"]

The --host 0.0.0.0 is probably required in Docker.  See for example ng serve not working in Docker container.  That special IP address means "listen on all interfaces", and it doesn't make sense to include it in a URL.

Of course you should be able to access it from localhost. The docker compose will create a bridge network if not otherwise specified so you should be able to reach it from localhost.
Bridge Network
Have you tried something like this?
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200

If it does not work I would like more information.
